# How do indexes work when searching with wildcards and returning specific columns

Tags: sql-server

So, in SQL Server I have a table that represents book records. Something like

```
No   title                type        publisher       etc...
------------------------------------------------------
118  'Book Title'         book        'publisher_1'
119  'Title'              book        'publisher_1'
120  'Title but longer'   ebook       'publisher_1'
121  'Book Title I like'  book        'publisher_1'
122  'Title'              ebook       'publisher_1'
```

I have the premade clustered index at column no and I made an index on column 'Title'.

This is the one I want to test (whether it helps the query or not).

So, when I run the following queries that happens:

- When I want to select the 'Title' and search with the condition `where title LIKE %Title%`, and it searches with and `index scan` (seems good)
- When I want to select the Title AND material and search with the condition `where title = 'Title'`, it searches with an `index seek` (all good here)
- When I want to select the Title AND material and search with the condition `where title LIKE 'Title%` it searches with `clustered index scan`

That last one I can not understand why it chooses `clustered index scan`
And also why it opts for `index seek` in the first one since I read the index wouldn't work with wildcards at the start and at the end

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using a wildcard implies using an "inequality" comparison. This comparison implies a scan of the index.

Nonclustered indexes are better for equality (exact) comparisons. You then obtain a index seek in your execution plan.

You should definitly add the column 'Title' to your clustered index. In your execution plan, you should notice some improvments, although you may still have an index scan. Clustered indexes (one par table) are more efficient for inequality comparison (range comparison or wildcard comparison)

The clustered index scan may be prefered by the sql engine, whereas a nonclustered index exists, because it consider it more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now the difference between one and two. However I still don't get why the clustered index is used in point 3 instead of just the non clustered index on title (resulting in just a n index scan)

Comment: @KseniaTsg sql engine is very smart and can optimize few things when you querying for rows. In your 3rd example sql engine decides that clustered index scan will be more efficient. Sequence reads from IO are cheaper that n number of random reads